# creating tables in DataBase though interfaces

Tags: .net, database, class, interface, orm

I have been told that someone implemented in .Net a way to create tables inside DataBase using interfaces instead of using *classes / POCOs*. Also said that uses a method o *SRM* (*subject relational mapping*) instead of *ORM* (*Object-relational mapping*)

I do not have any more info for that to explain it better. Tried to search it but couldn't find something related to that.

Has anyone any idea of what is this or provide any material to study that and understand how is that implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they use object attributes to generate sql or something internally then again it is orm. And the pocos probably refer to the standard C extensions of each sql subsystem they have.

See Google for postgress C api as well as mysql C api. Almost all sql systems have C bindings to essentially access a sql interpreter at a "lower level".

Comment: Thank you. I will check it. Most likely POCOS refer to standard C